# installation imagemagick with jasper

Tags: macos, imagemagick, macos-sierra, libtool

I install japer on MacOs Sierra

```
.
.   
 Pouring jasper-2.0.12.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
     /usr/local/Cellar/jasper/2.0.12: 39 files, 996.3KB
```

I already Installed Imagemagick with the path
`/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-3` and delete it

with the help of
    https://gist.github.com/facto/7156583

but when I try

```
 brew install imagemagick --with-jasper
```

brew install imagemagick --with-jasper

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
elasticsearch              logstash                   openmotif

Error: You must `brew link libtool` before imagemagick can be installed
```

`. on my system.

I got the error and solve with
  `brew link --overwrite libtool`

I install again but ignore --with-jasper

> imagemagick: this formula has no --with-jasper option so it will be
>   ignored!

Any idea How can I use jasper with Imagemagick

Comment: Not sure what has happened here. If you run `brew options imagemagick` it will tell you all the available options, but `Jasper` isn't listed so it isn't supported as an option. No idea why. If you try and install from source, the `./configure` command you would use also does not appear to have any `Jasper` options. I guess you are maybe supposed to use some other option - is it JPEG2000 support that you are ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: current versions of ImageMagick use openjpeg 2.1.0 or higher as the JP2 delegate. So you would need to install that rather than jasper for your JP2 delegate